# Return address from Google Maps Geocoder v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have the following function:

```
$(function() {
     var address = $("#address").text();
     var r;

     function encodeAddress() {
       geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       geocoder.geocode({'address' : address}, function(results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           results[0].geometry.location
           r = results[0].geometry.location
           console.log("inside:" + r);
         } else {
           alert("Google Maps had some trouble finding" + address + status);
         }
       });
     }

    encodeAddress()
    console.log("outside:" + r);
});
```

I am trying to return the geocoded address for use with Street View as well as Gmap.  Inside returns the correct value and the outside returns underfined.

All help is greatly appreciated, I did read somewhere else that it is not possible to return the value this way but had to check with the trusty StackOverflow community.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way, and call the outputGeo function within the Geocode's callback function.  Basically, you are accessing r before the Geocode callback and thus r is still undefined:

```
$(function() {
     var address = $("address").text();
     var r;

     function encodeAddress() {
       geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       geocoder.geocode({'address' : address}, function(results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           results[0].geometry.location;
           r = results[0].geometry.location;
           outputGeo(r);
         } else {
           alert("Google Maps had some trouble finding" + address + status);
         }
       });
     }

    encodeAddress();
    function outputGeo(result){
         console.log("outside:" + result);
    }
});
```

---

Here is an explanation of how Geocoding service works.

> Accessing the Geocoding service is
>   asynchronous, since the Google Maps
>   API needs to make a call to an
>   external server. For that reason, you
>   need to pass a callback method to
>   execute upon completion of the
>   request. This callback method
>   processes the result(s). Note that the
>   geocoder may return more than one
>   result.

Comment: Thanks @kjy112 this seems to be very close to what I need.  It is returning the value but I need to use it outside of the encodeAddress() function as this needs to be used in several places. How would I go about using the result globally?

Comment: @jnolte you can put all your "to do logics" in a function and call it after the Geocode returns within the callback function at the same time inject the return data into your global `var r`.  Basically, you wont' be able to access `r` until geocode returns.