# google maps geocoding

Tags: geocoding

hi i am having the same probem as here [Return address from Google Maps Geocoder v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517120/return-address-from-google-maps-geocoder-v3)  , i dont understand how to set my global variable to the return vlaue

i got this at the moment where b returns undefined

```
 var a;
 var b;
function outputGeo(result){
    b = result; 
     }


 geocoder.geocode({'latLng': event.latLng},function(results, status) {

         a =  results[1].formatted_address;
         outputGeo(a);
        });  
alert(b);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geocoder.geocode` is an asynchronous function because it's performing a JSONP request. In other words, before the results have come back, the `alert(b)` line is already being called. You need to put that `alert` line into the callback function after `outputGeo(a)`.

Javascript's a funny language. This async thing bit me until I researched JSONP and the synchrony of Javascript. I suggest you do the same. A great way to learn about this is to write a JSONP-request wrapper of your own. (Just a thought.)